# how to use preg_replace() in php?

Tags: php

Can anybody help me with preg_replace? I have an string where I need to filter this out:

```
health=0.30799794
```

"health=" Is there in the string every time. But the number behind is different. 
Is there a way to do it with perg_replace in PHP?

Comment: not clear... What you want?

Comment: What is your expected output? What you have tried so far?

Comment: I want to delete `health=0.30799794`. So basically replace it with nothing.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know is it that you are looking for or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are looking for this:

```
$filter = '/health=0.30799794/';
$str = 'I am not here and my health=0.30799794';

echo $str = preg_replace ($filter, "", $str); //I am not here and my
```

**Updates:**

Just change the filter:

`$filter = '/health=[0-9]*.[0-9]*/';`
OR
`$filter = '/health=\d*.\d*/';`

Comment: Thank you for that. But I have not described my problem correctly. Instead of `0.30799794` the number is different every time

Comment: Of course you don't describe, You need some more explanation in your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, but thanks for youre answer. I now got it to work by myself: `$out = preg_replace('/health=\d*.\d*/', "", $value);`

Comment: Okey, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
            $pattern    = "#(health=[0-9\.]*)#";
            $sample     = "The Student has not got the best health-status - health=0.30799794 and he is not so happy with it.";
            $result     = preg_replace($pattern, "", $sample);

            var_dump($result);
            //DUMPS: The Student has not got the best health-status -  and he is not so happy with it.
```